# How long can I freeze uncooked rice noodles for (not dried but in sealed bag)

Tags: freezing, storage

I live in a rural area and don't have transport so when I get chance to shop I tend to buy in semi bulk and I bought several packs of rice noodles (not the dried ones) and put them in the freezer. How long can I keep them in storage? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome pam! According to this article about rice noodles on  [everything2.com](http://everything2.com/title/Rice+noodles) , you should be able to store them frozen for up to 2 months. Excerpt below:

> If you really need to store them for a longer period, keep them in the fridge for up to a week, or in the freezer for up to 2 months.